# How to import a repository into another with Git

Tags: git, import, repository

I want to import the sources of an external repository into my repository. 
For example from this project:
https://github.com/SpongePowered/Sponge

Where "Mixin" is imported. I want to do the same thing, but I don't know how.

Comment: Wasn't there something like submodule? http://git-scm.com/book/de/v1/Git-Tools-Submodule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called `submodules`. They are mostly used when you want to use some other project inside your project without importing the project's code separately.

You can do it for your project by just adding a `submodule` to your project.

```
git submodule add https://github.com/SpongePowered/Sponge
```

[Read here for more info](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)